# Jshint - Variable is already defined and missing semicolon of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jshint

I defined a `reason` variable as javascript object inside a function, and then, use this object to define properties as following:

```
$scope.upsertReason = function() {
    var reason = {},
        reason.reasons = [],
        reason.scholarships = [];
}
```

I don't know why I always got the following error:

```
412 |            reason.reasons = [],
                       ^ 'reason' is already defined.
412 |            reason.reasons = [],
                       ^ Missing semicolon.
412 |            reason.reasons = [],
                       ^ Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.
412 |            reason.reasons = [],
                       ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
412 |            reason.reasons = [],
                        ^ Missing semicolon.
413 |            reason.scholarships = [];
                                        ^ Expected an assignment or function
```

I have verified that I didn't define the `reason` variable anywhere else in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: setting object property is NOT variable declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot declare a property of an object with `var` statement, because `var` statement expects the variable names not to contain invalid characters. And `.` is definitely an invalid character for an identifier name. So, you cannot declare a new variable called `reason.reasons` or `reason.scholarships`.

You should declare `reason` like this

```
var reason = {
    reasons: [],
    scholarships = []
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) said, you can either do this:

```
var reason = {
    reasons: [],
    scholarships = []
};
```

Or if you want to do it all separately, you can do:

```
var reason = {};
reason.reasons = [];
reason.scholarships = [];
```